# Persistent Placeholders in IE

Tags: asp.net, placeholder

I am styling a `ms-input-placeholder` with my `login.aspx` file for a RDWeb portal.  I want to implement [persistent placeholders](http://mrcoles.com/blog/persistent-placeholders-tutorial-focus/) on each username and password `textInputField`.  How can I do that?

Here is some working/example code I added which styles my username and password fields.  I cannot modify it in a way which implements persistent placeholders (placeholders that always show, even on focus, unless the textbox has text).

```
<style>
    .textInputField:-ms-input-placeholder {   
        color: #999999;
    }
    .textInputField:focus {
        background-color:yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my Jquery Plugin. The one you posted does not work properly in IE.

It will take the placeholder in text and password inputs and convert them to labels to act like placeholder and make it persistent.

This has animation with options. Available options are focusOpacity, focusSpeed, & fadeSpeed.

Just copy and paste Plugin code from Fiddle link below.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbhtek/d8ccC/)

HTML

```
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

CSS

```
.input-wrapper input {
z-index: 9999;
font-size: 14px;
height: 20px;
border: none;
background: transparent;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
outline: none;
}

.input-wrapper {
margin: 10px;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #000;
vertical-align: middle;
position: relative;
display: block;
}

.input-wrapper label {
z-index: 999;
color: gray;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: arial;
font-style: italic;
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
padding-left: 3px;
position: absolute; 
cursor: text;
}
```

Script with options

```
$(document).labelPlaceholder({focusOpacity:.5,focusSpeed:150,fadeSpeed:50});
```

Script using defaults

```
$(document).labelPlaceholder();
```